# Determining nested random effects using a generalized mixed linear model (in R)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, split-plot

I have a split-plot experiment, with irrigation as a main-plot factor (x2, Irr1 & Irr2) and fertilizer type (x4, F1-F4) as a split-plot factor. Within each experiment, each treatment is replicated 4 times. I have been doing these experiments over two years; in year 1, I had one treatment at location A, but in year 2, I had two experiments in year A and B. My response variable was end-of-season crop yield. The graphic below illustrates this:

[image: Figure 1: Experiment layouts. The split-plot design was used, with the main plot being irrigation, and the split-plot being fertilizer type. "Rep" indicates the replication within the experiment. The response variable was end-of-season yield.]

Figure 1: Experiment layouts. The split-plot design was used, with the main plot being irrigation, and the split-plot being fertilizer type. "Rep" indicates the replication within the experiment. The response variable was end-of-season yield. As a side note, each main- and split-plot factor were randomized differently from the other experiments.

Here is what my data look like (can be copied and pasted directly into R):

```
data <- data.frame(site = c('2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2021-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-A',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B',
                            '2022-B'),
                   rep = c(1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           1,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           2,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3,
                           3),
                   irr = c('irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr1',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2',
                           'irr2'),
                   fert = c('F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4',
                            'F1',
                            'F2',
                            'F3',
                            'F4'),
                   yield = c(66,
                             67,
                             89,
                             100,
                             42,
                             77,
                             69,
                             46,
                             59,
                             49,
                             70,
                             52,
                             57,
                             6,
                             19,
                             94,
                             11,
                             76,
                             86,
                             15,
                             37,
                             83,
                             75,
                             54,
                             65,
                             41,
                             67,
                             64,
                             74,
                             99,
                             74,
                             68,
                             34,
                             61,
                             52,
                             40,
                             78,
                             10,
                             91,
                             8,
                             10,
                             51,
                             5,
                             63,
                             57,
                             42,
                             54,
                             78,
                             16,
                             15,
                             15,
                             91,
                             80,
                             24,
                             74,
                             26,
                             11,
                             73,
                             47,
                             60,
                             59,
                             34,
                             78,
                             87,
                             62,
                             88,
                             86,
                             92,
                             98,
                             59,
                             96,
                             34))
```

I want to see if there is an interaction between site-year, irrigation, and fertilizer. **How should I specify my random effects?** I assume that there is some nesting involved since we are dealing with multiple site-years, but I am not sure.

Here is what I have done so far, but I'm not sure if this is correct:

```
library(nlme)
library(car)

data$site <- as.factor(data$site)
data$rep <- as.factor(data$rep)
data$irr <- as.factor(data$irr)
data$fert <- as.factor(data$fert)

# Construct the model
mod <- lmer(yield ~ site*irr*fert + (1|rep:irr), data = data)
Anova(mod, type = c("II"))
```

Currently, the `(1|rep:irr)` random effect accounts for the sub-plots, but do I need to account for the location?